# Custom imported rules disappearing after updating module.rules.inc

Tags: rules

I have rules imported from a custom module. They are defined in the `module.rules.inc` file.

They make use of custom conditions and actions which are defined in the same file as well.

Whenever I update **any** part of the code in `module.rules.inc` and clear cache, all custom rules disappear from the site.

To get them back working I have to uninstall the module completely and then install it again.

Any clues on what is going on? Any way to avoid this as it's prolonging the dev process?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this,I have the same issue..

Comment: Nope; unfortunately I didn't solve it still. I have to repeat the procedure whenever I make some changes to the rules.

Comment: I think this is a rules bug which has been fixed on the latest dev.Try this

Comment: Thanks for posting back - will check it and let you know.

Comment: any news about this?

Comment: Haven't worked with this for quite a while, but I think last time I did it was working OK. Give latest Rules a try.